# How to replace NaNs by preceding or next values in pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nan

Suppose I have a DataFrame with some `NaN`s:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, None, None], [None, None, 9]])
>>> df
    0   1   2
0   1   2   3
1   4 NaN NaN
2 NaN NaN   9
```

What I need to do is replace every `NaN` with the first non-`NaN` value in the same column above it. It is assumed that the first row will never contain a `NaN`. So for the previous example the result would be

```
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  4  2  3
2  4  2  9
```

I can just loop through the whole DataFrame column-by-column, element-by-element and set the values directly, but is there an easy (optimally a loop-free) way of achieving this?

Answer (score 402, accepted):

You could use the [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) method on the DataFrame and specify the method as `ffill` (forward fill):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, None, None], [None, None, 9]])
>>> df.fillna(method='ffill')
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  4  2  3
2  4  2  9
```

This method...

> propagate[s] last valid observation forward to next valid

To go the opposite way, there's also a `bfill` method.

This method doesn't modify the DataFrame inplace - you'll need to rebind the returned DataFrame to a variable or else specify `inplace=True`:

```
df.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
```

Comment: What if the blank cell was in the column names index (i.e., a couple of the columns didn't have names but did have data.  Is there a way to use bfill or ffill to fill the blank column index cell with the cell in the row immediately below it?  For instance: df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [2, 4, 8],
                   'col2': [2, 0, 0],
                   '': [10, 2, 1]},
                  index=['falcon', 'dog', 'spider''])
How could I use bfill or ffill to change the name of the third column to 10 (which is the value of the row immediately below the blank third column name?  Thanks!

Answer (score 59):

The accepted answer is perfect. I had a related but slightly different situation where I had to fill in forward but only within groups. In case someone has the same need, know that fillna works on a DataFrameGroupBy object.

```
>>> example = pd.DataFrame({'number':[0,1,2,nan,4,nan,6,7,8,9],'name':list('aaabbbcccc')})
>>> example
  name  number
0    a     0.0
1    a     1.0
2    a     2.0
3    b     NaN
4    b     4.0
5    b     NaN
6    c     6.0
7    c     7.0
8    c     8.0
9    c     9.0
>>> example.groupby('name')['number'].fillna(method='ffill') # fill in row 5 but not row 3
0    0.0
1    1.0
2    2.0
3    NaN
4    4.0
5    4.0
6    6.0
7    7.0
8    8.0
9    9.0
Name: number, dtype: float64
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, ty

Answer (score 24):

One thing that I noticed when trying this solution is that if you have N/A at the start or the end of the array, ffill and bfill don't quite work.  You need both.

```
In [224]: df = pd.DataFrame([None, 1, 2, 3, None, 4, 5, 6, None])

In [225]: df.ffill()
Out[225]:
     0
0  NaN
1  1.0
...
7  6.0
8  6.0

In [226]: df.bfill()
Out[226]:
     0
0  1.0
1  1.0
...
7  6.0
8  NaN

In [227]: df.bfill().ffill()
Out[227]:
     0
0  1.0
1  1.0
...
7  6.0
8  6.0
```

Comment: Brilliant. I needed exactly this for my problem. Filling both before and after. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Great. I need this solution. Thanks

Answer (score 19):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with the `method='ffill'` option. `'ffill'` stands for 'forward fill' and will propagate last valid observation forward. The alternative is `'bfill'` which works the same way, but backwards.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, None, None], [None, None, 9]])
df = df.fillna(method='ffill')

print(df)
#   0  1  2
#0  1  2  3
#1  4  2  3
#2  4  2  9
```

There is also a direct synonym function for this, [`pandas.DataFrame.ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html), to make things simpler.

Answer (score 13):

**Only one column version**

- Fill NAN with **last valid value**

```
df[column_name].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
```

- Fill NAN with **next valid value**

```
df[column_name].fillna(method='backfill', inplace=True)
```

Comment: How do fill values of multiple columns but not all?

Comment: @Alex check this, it should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34913590/fillna-in-multiple-columns-in-place-in-python-pandas

Answer (score 13):

Just agreeing with `ffill` method, but one extra info is that you can limit the forward fill with keyword argument `limit`.

```
>>> import pandas as pd    
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [None, None, 6], [None, None, 9]])

>>> df
     0    1   2
0  1.0  2.0   3
1  NaN  NaN   6
2  NaN  NaN   9

>>> df[1].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
>>> df
     0    1    2
0  1.0  2.0    3
1  NaN  2.0    6
2  NaN  2.0    9
```

Now with `limit` keyword argument

```
>>> df[0].fillna(method='ffill', limit=1, inplace=True)

>>> df
     0    1  2
0  1.0  2.0  3
1  1.0  2.0  6
2  NaN  2.0  9
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use `fillna` to remove or replace NaN values.

**NaN *Remove***

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, None, None], [None, None, 9]])

df.fillna(method='ffill')
     0    1    2
0  1.0  2.0  3.0
1  4.0  2.0  3.0
2  4.0  2.0  9.0
```

**NaN *Replace***

```
df.fillna(0) # 0 means What Value you want to replace 
     0    1    2
0  1.0  2.0  3.0
1  4.0  0.0  0.0
2  0.0  0.0  9.0
```

Reference [pandas.DataFrame.fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

Answer (score 9):

`ffill` now has it's own method [`pd.DataFrame.ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html)

```
df.ffill()

     0    1    2
0  1.0  2.0  3.0
1  4.0  2.0  3.0
2  4.0  2.0  9.0
```

Answer (score 4):

There's also [pandas.Interpolate](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html), which I think gives one more control

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, None, None], [None, None, 9]])

df=df.interpolate(method="pad",limit=None, downcast="infer") #downcast keeps dtype as int 
print(df)  

   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  4  2  3
2  4  2  9
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, we have time series from different devices but some devices could not send any value during some period. So we should create NA values for every device and time period and after that do fillna.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["device1", 1, 'first val of device1'], ["device2", 2, 'first val of device2'], ["device3", 3, 'first val of device3']])
df.pivot(index=1, columns=0, values=2).fillna(method='ffill').unstack().reset_index(name='value')
```

Result:

```
        0   1   value
0   device1     1   first val of device1
1   device1     2   first val of device1
2   device1     3   first val of device1
3   device2     1   None
4   device2     2   first val of device2
5   device2     3   first val of device2
6   device3     1   None
7   device3     2   None
8   device3     3   first val of device3
```