# Fillna in multiple columns in place in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataFrame of mixed types, some are strings and some are numbers. I would like to replace the NAN values in string columns by '.', and the NAN values in float columns by 0.

Consider this small fictitious example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Jack','Sue',pd.np.nan,'Bob','Alice','John'],
    'A': [1, 2.1, pd.np.nan, 4.7, 5.6, 6.8],
    'B': [.25, pd.np.nan, pd.np.nan, 4, 12.2, 14.4],
    'City':['Seattle','SF','LA','OC',pd.np.nan,pd.np.nan]})
```

Now, I can do it in 3 lines:

```
df['Name'].fillna('.',inplace=True)
df['City'].fillna('.',inplace=True)
df.fillna(0,inplace=True)
```

Since this is a small dataframe, 3 lines is probably ok. In my real example (which I cannot share here due to data confidentiality reasons), I have many more string columns and numeric columns. SO I end up writing many lines just for fillna. Is there a concise way of doing this?

Comment: In your real example, for the string columns are the `NaN` or the string `'NaN'`?

Comment: NaN, not the string 'NaN'

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You could use [`apply`](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjEkvbtobrKAhXJkSwKHVRRAxgQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpandas.pydata.org%2Fpandas-docs%2Fversion%2F0.17.1%2Fgenerated%2Fpandas.DataFrame.apply.html&usg=AFQjCNEV-3rhym9xF5j7u78SpzSm6Ra4PA) for your columns with checking `dtype` whether it's `numeric` or not by checking [`dtype.kind`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.kind.html):

```
res = df.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(0) if x.dtype.kind in 'biufc' else x.fillna('.'))

print(res)
     A      B     City   Name
0  1.0   0.25  Seattle   Jack
1  2.1   0.00       SF    Sue
2  0.0   0.00       LA      .
3  4.7   4.00       OC    Bob
4  5.6  12.20        .  Alice
5  6.8  14.40        .   John
```

Comment: Very elegant! Can you confirm that `'biufc'` is for boolean, integer, unicode, float & complex data types?

Comment: @Lenwood yes, you could follow the link for [`dtype.kind`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.kind.html) to check that.

Comment: This is great. What if I wanted to fill in the mean of the column instead of "0"?

Comment: @Peter I guess you could replace `x.fillna(0)` -> `x.fillna(x.mean())`

Answer (score 89):

Came across this page while looking for an answer to this problem, but didn't like the existing answers.  I ended up finding something better in the [DataFrame.fillna documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html), and figured I'd contribute for anyone else that happens upon this.

If you have multiple columns, but only want to replace the `NaN` in a subset of them, you can use:

```
df.fillna({'Name':'.', 'City':'.'}, inplace=True)
```

This also allows you to specify different replacements for each column.  And if you want to go ahead and fill all remaining `NaN` values, you can just throw another `fillna` on the end:

```
df.fillna({'Name':'.', 'City':'.'}, inplace=True).fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

---

**Edit (22 Apr 2021)**

Functionality (presumably / apparently) changed since original post, and you can no longer chain 2 `inplace` `fillna()` operations. You can still chain, but now **must assign that chain to the `df`** instead of modifying in place, e.g. like so:

```
df = df.fillna({'Name':'.', 'City':'.'}).fillna(0)
```

Comment: @Make42 Not a coding error; the intention was to replace the values in-place in the dataframe.

Comment: Please check your answer: If you use inplace, then the return value is `None`. Thus you will will fill `'Name'` and `'City'` with `'.'` in `df`. After that you return `None` and get an error trying to use your second `fillna` on the `None` value. If you now only remove the first  `ìnplace=True` you do not get THAT error. However, now you create a data frame in memory (with no Python symbol pointing to it), which nan-values are replaced by 0. The second `fillna` return - again - `None`, which we cannot use. Now you do have the desired data frame somewhere in memory, but you cannot reference it.

Comment: Ugh...it worked as written when it was written, but I guess they've gone and updated something that broke it.

Comment: To be honest, I have been using pandas for longer than 2018 and I cannot remember that this was different at any point than it is now, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: `inplace` is the scourge anyway: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529. Also, afaik `inplace` has always returned None, that's kind of the point. You either use `inplace`, or you chain, but not both together. To use `inplace` in this scenario you'd need to break it into 2 lines.

Answer (score 28):

You can either list the string columns by hand or glean them from `df.dtypes`.  Once you have the list of string/object columns, you can call `fillna` on all those columns at once.

```
# str_cols = ['Name','City']
str_cols = df.columns[df.dtypes==object]
df[str_cols] = df[str_cols].fillna('.')
df = df.fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 3):

define a function:

```
def myfillna(series):
    if series.dtype is pd.np.dtype(float):
        return series.fillna(0)
    elif series.dtype is pd.np.dtype(object):
        return series.fillna('.')
    else:
        return series
```

you can add other elif statements if you want to fill a column of a different dtype in some other way. Now apply this function over all columns of the dataframe

```
df = df.apply(myfillna)
```

this is the same as 'inplace'

Comment: This makes sense to write as a function. But wouldn't we need to write it as `for col in df.columns: df[col]=df.apply(myfillna)` ? The function is returning a series, and we replace the whole dataframe  with this.

Comment: no because by default apply has the parameter axis=0 which means to apply the function over each column and then returns the result as a dataframe with the new columns.

Comment: so actually df.apply(myfillna) is doing what you suggest behind the scenes.

Comment: Ok, it makes sense.. And I have tried it, and it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler way, that can be done in one line:

```
df.fillna({'Name':0,'City':0},inplace=True)
```

Not an awesome improvement but if you multiply it by 100, writting only the column names + ':0' is way faster than copying and pasting everything 100 times.

Answer (score 1):

The most concise and readable way to accomplish this, especially with many columns is to use `df.select_dtypes.columns`.
([`df.select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html), [`df.columns`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.columns.html))

`df.select_dtypes` returns a new `df` containing only the columns that match the dtype you need.

`df.columns` returns a list of the column names in your `df`.

Full code:

```
float_column_names = df.select_dtypes(float).columns
df[float_column_names] = df[float_column_names].fillna(0)

string_column_names = df.select_dtypes(object).columns
df[string_column_names] df[string_column_names].fillna('.')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace a list of columns ("lst") with the same value ("v")

```
def nan_to_zero(df, lst, v):
    d = {x:v for x in lst}
    df.fillna(d, inplace=True)
    return df
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to specify individual per-column replacement values, you can do it this way:

```
df[['Name', 'City']].fillna('.',inplace=True)
```

If you don't like inplace (like me) you can do it like this:

```
columns = ['Name', 'City']
df[columns] = df.copy()[columns].fillna('.')
```

The .copy() is added to avoid the SettingWithCopyWarning, which is designed to warn you that the original values of a dataframe is overwritten, which is what we want.

If you don't like that syntax, you can see this question to see other ways of dealing with this: [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

Comment: "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame"

Comment: @Ben, updated the answer with a way to avoid the warning

Answer (score -2):

Much easy way is  :`dt.replace(pd.np.nan, "NA")`.
In case you want other replacement, you should use the next:`dt.replace("pattern", "replaced by (new pattern)")`

Comment: This is just a different way of writing the standard `df.fillna('NA', inplace=True)` so you're not really gaining anything, plus it's a less standard way of filling `NaN` values in pandas.

Comment: No, its more general than what you think. this "dt.replace("pattern", "replaced by (new pattern)")"is given the programmer more choice to use any pattern to replace.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of replacing multiple specific columns at once and advises going against convention for a very standard practice in pandas.