# Cannot fill NaN values in multiple columns by lambda in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am attempting to fill all float columns NaN values with 0 in my DataFrame `all_files_d` then put it in either an empty list or DataFrame called `ts`.

A sample of my dats is as such:

```
 ColX              ColY
 56.9              6.4
 67.5              NaN
 NaN               8.9
 NaN               NaN
```

I have tried to follow this questions code as it seems to have worked for some users but there appears to be NaN values and it hasn't filled anything:

[Fillna in multiple columns in place in Python Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34913590/fillna-in-multiple-columns-in-place-in-python-pandas)

This is my code:

```
ts = []
all_files_d.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(0, inplace = True) if x.dtype.kind
 in 'f' else x.fillna('.', inplace = True), axis = 1)

ts.append(all_files_d)
```

I would hope to have the following results with all NaNs filled with 0. Thanks in advance.

```
 ColX              ColY
 56.9              6.4
 67.5              0
 0                 8.9
 0                 0
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) with [`pd.to_numeric()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html):

tested with(added an extra string column):

```
df['Colz']=['abc',np.nan,'def',np.nan]
print(df)

   ColX ColY Colz
0  56.9  6.4  abc
1  67.5  NaN  NaN
2   NaN  8,9  def
3   NaN  NaN  NaN
```

---

```
df.combine_first(df.apply(lambda x: \
      pd.to_numeric(x,errors='coerce')).dropna(how='all',axis=1).fillna(0))
```

**Output**

```
   ColX ColY Colz
0  56.9  6.4  abc
1  67.5    0  NaN
2   0.0  8,9  def
3   0.0    0  NaN
```

EDIT, for fetching float dtypes and filling with NaNs:

```
m=df.select_dtypes('float').columns 
df.loc[:,m]=df.loc[:,m].fillna(0) 
print(df)
```

Comment: Still have NaNs which is strange. Is this an inplace method?

Comment: @geds133 no, you have to assign it `df=df.combine_first(.....)` and then print(df)

Comment: @geds133 No problem. :) 1 more thing, by the example if you have data like `8,9` is this a typo or you have strings in float columns?

Comment: @geds133 No problem. :) 1 more thing, by the example if you have data like `8,9` is this a typo or you have strings in float columns?

Comment: It was a typo haved fixed in the question now :)!

Comment: @geds133 then use `m=df.select_dtypes('float').columns` 
`df.loc[:,m]=df.loc[:,m].fillna(0)` 
`print(df)` it is really important that you paste the exact data, else people might get confused, here this solution was not required if the columns are all floats. :)

Comment: Thanks. You may want to edit your answer and add the correct one in, also changing my typing error for clarity for others.

Answer (score 0):

Use `df.select_dtype()`

```
# fillna to float64 columns
ts = df.select_dtypes(include=['float64']).fillna(0) 

# merge data
df.join(ts, lsuffix="_").reindex(df.columns, axis=1)
```

Comment: Still contains NaNs. I don't want to directly fill ts either, I want to append at the end so i can do other operations in between.

Comment: what the df.dtypes say about those columns with remaining NaNs? probably they are `object` type??

Comment: They are float64

Comment: Again though, I don't want to assign straight to `ts`, only append.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC,

```
ts = df.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(0) if x.dtypes == float else x.fillna('.'))


    ColX    ColY
0   56.9    6.4
1   67.5    0.0
2   0.0     8.9
3   0.0     0.0
```

Comment: The expected output fills the NaN in the said column by 0 so I assume 8,9 is a typo. Will see, its not very clear as of now

Comment: Still have NaNs. I'm sure there is something not quite right with my data here but I cannot figure out why there are continual NaN values left over in float64 columns.

Comment: what is the output of df.dtypes?

Comment: Output for the columns are float64