# how can we replace empty cells in dataset with mean in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dataset

[image: 1[![2[![3]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZ2fn.jpg)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkVJN.jpg)

I need to convert float data to use decsition tree, every time I apply label encoder an error emerges: argument must be a string or number

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fillna in multiple columns in place in Python Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34913590/fillna-in-multiple-columns-in-place-in-python-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataFrame.fillna to fill the nan's. Try `df=df.fillna(df.mean())`