# How to fill dataframe content NA value in empty cell?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, nan

I have a dataframe df:

```
                  Open    Volume  Adj Close     Ticker  
Date                                                                   
2006-11-22  140.750000   45505300   114.480649   SPY
```

I want to change df to another dataframe Open price like below:

```
                  SPY    AGG  
Date                                                                   
2006-11-22  140.750000   NA
```

It only use open's data and two tickers, so how to change one dataframe to another?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace NaNs by preceding values in pandas DataFrame?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905295/how-to-replace-nans-by-preceding-values-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: There is only one row in `df`?

Comment: yes,there is only one row in df

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `DataFrame` constructor with [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by list of `ticker` `L`:

```
L = ['SPY','AGG']
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'SPY': [df.Open.iloc[0]]}, 
                   index=[df.index[0]])

df1 = df1.reindex(columns=L)
print (df1)
               SPY  AGG
2006-11-22  140.75  NaN
```

You can use [`read_html`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html) for find list of `Tickers`:

```
df2 = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies', header=0)[0]
#print (df2)

#filter only Ticker symbols starts with SP
df2 = df2[df2['Ticker symbol'].str.startswith('SP')]
print (df2)
    Ticker symbol                  Security SEC filings  \
407           SPG  Simon Property Group Inc     reports   
415          SPGI          S&P Global, Inc.     reports   
418          SPLS              Staples Inc.     reports   

                GICS Sector               GICS Sub Industry  \
407             Real Estate                           REITs   
415              Financials  Diversified Financial Services   
418  Consumer Discretionary                Specialty Stores   

       Address of Headquarters Date first added      CIK  
407      Indianapolis, Indiana              NaN  1063761  
415         New York, New York              NaN    64040  
418  Framingham, Massachusetts              NaN   791519  

#convert column to list, add SPY because missing
L = ['SPY'] + df2['Ticker symbol'].tolist() 
print (L)
['SPY', 'SPG', 'SPGI', 'SPLS']

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'SPY': [df.Open.iloc[0]]}, 
                   index=[df.index[0]])

df1 = df1.reindex(columns=L)
print (df1)
               SPY  SPG  SPGI  SPLS
2006-11-22  140.75  NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Or I should add one row AGG ticker in df( all NaN)?Then use "df = pd.pivot(index=df.index, columns=df.Ticker, values=df.Open)"

Comment: Is possible add all ticker to `list` ?

Comment: Could you explain how to add all tickers to list?

Comment: Hard question, is possible find some table in web? Can you help me?

Comment: I find all s&p500 tickers:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies

Comment: You can use 4 or 5 tickers to test it. Thank you.

Comment: Please check answer, `SPY` was missing, so I add it manually to another `Tickers`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a list of data frame `df_list` for different tickers and every item of of list have the same look of the `df` in your example

You can first concatenate them into one frame with

```
df1 = pd.concat(df_list)
```

Then with

```
df1[["Open", "Ticker"]].reset_index().set_index(["Date", "Ticker"]).unstack()
```

It should give you an output like

```
            Open
Ticker      AGG     SPY
Date        
2006-11-22  NAN  140.75
```