# How to fill missing dates in pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

MY DataFrame contains several data for each date. in my date column date has entered only for the first data of the day, for rest of the data of the day there is only sparse value. How can I fill all the all the unfilled date values with corresponding date?

[Following is the snippet of my data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYgKL.png)

Comment: Please provide data as plain text, not images. Also, do you want a python/pandas solution, an R solution or both?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace NaNs by preceding values in pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905295/how-to-replace-nans-by-preceding-values-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Please do not post images of code or data.

Comment: Spamming tags for  is not cool. "pandas" has nothing to do with R (and I'm being kind by not referring maliciously to python-related ilk),

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python

```
df['Date']=df['Date'].replace({'':np.nan}).ffill()
```

In R

```
library(zoo)
df$Date[df$Date=='']=NA
df$Date=na.locf(df$Date)
```

Comment: Thank you Wen! It is working and I learned something which I didn't know. May you please elaborate the code to me!

Comment: @DharitParmar Basically R and Python are same here, replace the blank with np.nan, `ffill` and  `na.locf` is to fill the `na` by using the previous not null value

Comment: @ Wen Understood, Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use fillna function.

```
# Say df is your dataframe
# To fill values forward use:
df.fillna(method='ffill') 

# To fill values backward use:
df.fillna(method='bfill')
```