# how to use LOCF in this time series data for pandas in python

Tags: python, locf

If I have a data as given below , I need to fil the last observations based on the id when it last appeared, the data is as given below  -

ID   OpenDate         ObsDate    Amount  ClosedDate Output

1    10-12-1990       15-08-1991  20     15-08-1992     2

3    10-12-1993       15-12-1993  25     15-08-1994     1

5    10-12-1995       25-11-1997  0      18-08-1998     1

1    NaN              NaN         NaN    NaN         NaN

3    NaN              NaN         NaN    NaN         NaN

The expected output should be the filed out values FOR 1 AND 3 IDS with the previous values of 1 and 3 i.e

ID   OpenDate          ObsDate    Amount  ClosedDate Output

1    10-12-1990        15-08-1991    20     15-08-1992  2

3    10-12-1993        15-12-1993    25     15-08-1994  1

5    10-12-1995        25-11-1997    0      18-08-1998  1

1    10-12-1990        15-08-1991    20     15-08-1992  2

3    10-12-1993        15-12-1993    25     15-08-1994  1

Consider this to be a dataframe,the inputs needed for python.

Comment: It was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47024931/how-to-fill-missing-dates-in-pandas-dataframe