# Populating the column value with previous when NaN

Tags: python, string, list, pandas, dataframe

I have a `pd.Series` that looks like this:

```
>>> series
0     This is a foo bar something...
1                                NaN
2                                NaN
3        foo bar indeed something...
4                                NaN
5                                NaN
6               foo your bar self...
7                                NaN
8                                NaN
```

**How do I populate the NaN column values with the previous non NaN value in the series?**

I have tried this:

```
new_column = []

for row in list(series):
    if type(row) == str:
        new_column.append(row)
    else:
        new_column.append(new_column[-1])

series = pd.Series(new_column)
```

But is there another way to do the same in `pandas`?

Comment: Look into fillna (ffill)

Comment: Awesome thanks for the pointer to `ffill`.

Comment: Yeah its a dupe so didn't post it as an answer:)

Comment: Do you have t link to the dupe?

Comment: Here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905295/how-to-replace-nans-by-preceding-values-in-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna):

> **DataFrame.fillna(value=None, method=None, axis=None, inplace=False, limit=None, downcast=None, **kwargs)**
>
> ...
>
> **method** : {‘backfill’, ‘bfill’, ‘pad’, ‘ffill’, None}, default None
>
> Method to use for filling holes in reindexed Series pad / ffill: propagate last valid observation forward to next valid backfill / bfill: use NEXT valid observation to fill gap

So:

```
series.fillna(method='ffill')
```

Some explanation:

- `ffill` / `pad`: Forward fill is to use the value from previous row that isn't NA and populate the NA value. `pad` is just a verbose alias to `ffill`.
- `bfill` / `backfill`: Back fill is to use the value from the next row that isn't NA to populate the NA value. `backfill` is just verbose alias to `bfill`.

**In code**:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.NaN
nan

>>> series = pd.Series([np.NaN, 'abc', np.NaN, np.NaN, 'def', np.NaN, np.NaN])

>>> series
0    NaN
1    abc
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    def
5    NaN
6    NaN
dtype: object

>>> series.fillna(method='ffill')
0    NaN
1    abc
2    abc
3    abc
4    def
5    def
6    def
dtype: object

>>> series.fillna(method='bfill')
0    abc
1    abc
2    def
3    def
4    def
5    NaN
6    NaN
dtype: object
```

Comment: I want to know is there any difference between `ffill` and `pad`? what about `bfill` and `backfill`