# slow loop using panda

Tags: performance, pandas, loops

I am trying to replace each nan value in a series by the previous row's value. The data looks like:

16.5

NaN

16.5

NaN

NaN

16

NaN

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.read_csv('test.csv')
AskPrice=df.AskPrice
for i, line in enumerate(AskPrice):
if np.isnan(line):
    AskPrice[i]=AskPrice[i-1]
print(AskPrice)
```

I want it to be:

16.5

16.5

16.5

16.5

16.5

16

16

I got the result but it took ages to complete the task. Is there a faster way? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace NaNs by preceding values in pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905295/how-to-replace-nans-by-preceding-values-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
df.fillna(method='ffill')
```

Comment: Perhaps `df.ffill()`

Comment: Okay, I will do some investigations! Thank you!

Comment: @Bharath it is exactly the same see [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html)

Comment: Yes, I know I meant you to add the short form as well

Comment: @xxyy are you trying to do on all the dataframe or on a given column?

Comment: On a specific column. It works now. Thank you very much!