# Overwrite NaNs in a column based on identifier

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains some `NaN`-values in a `t`-column. The values in the `t`-column belong to a certain `id` and should be the same per `id`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"t"  :   [4, 4, 1, 1, float('nan'), 2, 2, 2, float('nan'), 10],
                   "id":    [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3 , 3, 4, 4]})
```

Therefore, I would like to overwrite the  `NaN` in `t` with the non-`NaN` in `t` for the respective `id` and ultimately end up with

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"t"  :   [4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 10, 10],
                   "id":    [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3 , 3, 4, 4]})
```

Comment: similar to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905295/how-to-replace-nans-by-preceding-values-in-pandas-dataframe) ?

Comment: @HamzaHaider No, not quite. If you read my OP, then my example is based on an `id` that we use to identify the correct `t` to use - it is not necessarily based preceding values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

New strategy... Create a map by dropping na and reassign using loc and mask.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"t"  :   [4, 4, 1, 1, float('nan'), 2, 2, 2, float('nan'), 10],
                   "id":    [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3 , 3, 4, 4]})

# create mask
m = pd.isna(df['t'])

# create map
#d = df[~m].set_index('id')['t'].drop_duplicates()
d = df[~m].set_index('id')['t'].to_dict()

# assign map to the slice of the dataframe containing nan
df.loc[m,'t'] = df.loc[m,'id'].map(d)

print(df)
```

df returns:

```
   id     t
0   1   4.0
1   1   4.0
2   2   1.0
3   2   1.0
4   3   2.0
5   3   2.0
6   3   2.0
7   3   2.0
8   4  10.0
9   4  10.0
```

Comment: I think you have better solution :)

Comment: For some odd reason `drop_duplicates` removes all the rows I have? I use `isnull` as `isna` isn't in my Panda-library

Comment: @N08 ok, what version are you running on? Did you consider upgrading your pandas? You can also try to_dict() (**updated my answer**)

Comment: It works with `to_dict`, thanks. I am running `0.20.1`

Answer (score 2):

Use [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for same column with [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
df['t'] = df.sort_values(['id','t']).groupby('id')['t'].transform('first')
```

Alternative solution is [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series` created by [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) with [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df['t'] = df['id'].map(df.dropna(subset=['t']).drop_duplicates('id').set_index('id')['t'])

print (df)
   id     t
0   1   4.0
1   1   4.0
2   2   1.0
3   2   1.0
4   3   2.0
5   3   2.0
6   3   2.0
7   3   2.0
8   4  10.0
9   4  10.0
```

Comment: Yes, this was better. I think however my solution can be faster for large sets as it only reassigns a slice using loc, don't you think?

Comment: @AntonvBR - It is possible, the best test it.