# Fill NaN values in dataframe with previous values in column

Tags: python, dataframe

Hi I have a dataframe with some missing values ex:

[image]

The black numbers 40 and 50 are the values already inputted and the red ones are to autofill from the previous values. Row 2 is blank as there is no previous number to fill.

Any idea how I can do this efficiently? I was trying loops but maybe there is a better way

Comment: Call `fillna(method='bfill')`.

Comment: Please dont post image of codes or dfs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace NaNs by preceding values in pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905295/how-to-replace-nans-by-preceding-values-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It can be done easily with `ffill` method in pandas [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html).

To illustrate the working consider the following sample dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

df['Vals'] = [1, 2, 3, np.nan, np.nan, 6, 7, np.nan, 8]

    Vals
0   1.0
1   2.0
2   3.0
3   NaN
4   5.0
5   6.0
6   7.0
7   NaN
8   8.0
```

To fill the missing value do this

```
df['Vals'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)

    Vals
0   1.0
1   2.0
2   3.0
3   3.0
4   3.0
5   6.0
6   7.0
7   7.0
8   8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a direct synonym function for this, `pandas.DataFrame.ffill`

```
df['Vals',inplace=True]
```