# Python: How to select certain columns by slicing for replacing NaN values after groupby?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Assuming we have a df as follows

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Col1' : [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
                   'Col2' : [5, 6, 8, 3, 7, 8, 5],
                  'Col3' : [2, None, None, 3, None, None, 4],
                  'Col4' : [3, None,5, None, 8, None, 66],
                  'Col5': [None, 8, 6, None, 9, 6,None],
                  'Col6' : [3,5,2,5,2,7,9]})
```

I wanted to replace the `None` values in the columns `Col3`, `Col4` and `Col5` using the solution suggested by jjs [in this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905295/how-to-replace-nans-by-preceding-values-in-pandas-dataframe) after applying `groupby` on the first column `Col1`.

The way I did is

```
df = df.groupby('Col1')['Col3','Col4','Col5'].ffill().bfill()
```

but it is a lot of work for mentioning the columns manually.

So, I wanted to know how can I choose the columns `Col3`, `Col4` and `Col5` by slicing?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean choose by slicing?

Comment: Something like using `.iloc[2:5]` to get the desired columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tbh, I'm not sure I understand your question.

As far as I see, you can just do straightforward

```
df.groupby('Col1').ffill().bfill()
```

because `ffill()` and `bfill()` just won't change your columns with no `NaN`s.

Now, if you know beforehand which columns you need to backfill/ffill and want to reduce verbosity, you may just save them in a `cols` variable

```
cols = ['Col3','Col4','Col5']
df[cols] = df.groupby('Col1')[cols].ffill().bfill()
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess I got confused with its implementation. The method suggested by you worked.

Answer (score 2):

this solution fills all NaN-columns in the way you want:

```
df.groupby('Col1')[df.columns[df.isnull().any()]].ffill().bfill()
```

Comment: If you are to `ffill` and `bbill` all columns with `NaN`, why not just fill all columns? `df.groupby('Col1').ffill().bfill()`

Comment: Hey, @Christian. I tried doing that, and it's filling the NaN-columns alright, but it is dropping the columns that have no NaN values like Col2 and Col6

Comment: Hey @KashyapMaheshwari . Ah ok. misunderstood your desired output.

Comment: @RafaelC i interpreted the desired output to just be the NaN-columns

Comment: @RafaelC of course your solution is more desirable if all columns are wanted.