# How to use groupby with nan value in groupby column

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I have the following Dataframe:
[Original Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yn52V.png)
I want the following output: 
[output Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8iUA.png)

I have tried using groupby on "Container" column (and sum and other columns) but it only gives the first row as output.

I am very new to python and pandas. and not sure if am doing it correct. 
Some of the answer of slimier questions are too advanced for me to understand. 
I am just wondering if i can get the output with just 2/3 lines of coding.

Comment: Could you post your code on trying it and the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expected result exactly as the one you showed as "Output Dataframe": first "NaN" values in "Container" column of your Original Dataframe must replaced with the corresponding immediate upper value. I added more "NaN" values to exemplify:

Original DataFrame:

```
df
       Container   SB No  Pkgs  CBM  Weight
257  CXRU1219452  195375  1650   65   23000
259  BEAU4883430  140801    26    3     575
260          NaN  140868    60    8    1153
261          NaN  140824    11    1     197
262          NaN  140851   253   32    4793
263          NaN  140645    14    1     278
264          NaN  140723     5    0      71
265          NaN  140741     1    0      22
266          NaN  140768     5    0      93
268  SZLU9366565  189355  1800   65   23000
259  ZBCD1234567  100000   100   10    1000
260          NaN  100000   100   10    1000
261          NaN  100000   100   10    1000
262          NaN  100000   100   10    1000
```

Use "fillna" function with method "ffill" as suggested by [https://stackoverflow.com/a/27905350/6057650][1]

Then you will get "Container" column without "NaN" values:

```
df=df.fillna(method='ffill')
df    
       Container   SB No  Pkgs  CBM  Weight
257  CXRU1219452  195375  1650   65   23000
259  BEAU4883430  140801    26    3     575
260  BEAU4883430  140868    60    8    1153
261  BEAU4883430  140824    11    1     197
262  BEAU4883430  140851   253   32    4793
263  BEAU4883430  140645    14    1     278
264  BEAU4883430  140723     5    0      71
265  BEAU4883430  140741     1    0      22
266  BEAU4883430  140768     5    0      93
268  SZLU9366565  189355  1800   65   23000
259  ZBCD1234567  100000   100   10    1000
260  ZBCD1234567  100000   100   10    1000
261  ZBCD1234567  100000   100   10    1000
262  ZBCD1234567  100000   100   10    1000
```

Now you can get the expected "Output DataFrame" using groupby:

```
df.groupby(['Container']).sum()

               SB No  Pkgs  CBM  Weight
Container                              
BEAU4883430  1126221   375   45    7182
CXRU1219452   195375  1650   65   23000
SZLU9366565   189355  1800   65   23000
ZBCD1234567   400000   400   40    4000
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could `groupby` and `sum` like below. The `dropna` will drop the `NaN`/empty values in your `DataFrame`.

```
df.dropna().groupby(['Container']).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

d =   [['CXRU',195, 1650,65,23000],
       ['BEAU',140, 26, 3, 575], 
       ['NaN', 140, 60 , 8, 1153]]
df=pd.DataFrame(mylist,columns=['Container','SB No', 'Pkgs', 'CBM','Weight'])
df
```

[image]

```
sel= df['Container']!='NaN'
df[sel]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['aaa', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'bbb', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'aaa', 'NaN'],
                  'values':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]})

df

for i in range(len(df)):

```
if df.iloc[i,0] == "NaN":

    df.iloc[i,0] = df.iloc[i-1,0]
```

df.groupby('id').sum()

Comment: I don't know to write answer.

Comment: Because, today is my first day to stack_overflow. (I can't english too.)