# Copying and replacing Pandas cell values

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to grab a given value in a Pandas column and change it to a previous row value?

For instance, I have this Dataframe:

`Date        Price   Signal
2018-01-01  13380.00    1
2018-01-02  14675.11    0
2018-01-03  14919.51    0
2018-01-04  15059.54    0
2018-01-05  16960.39    0
2018-01-06  17069.79    -1
2018-01-07  16150.03    0
2018-01-08  14902.54    0
2018-01-09  14400.00    1
2018-01-10  14907.09    0
2018-01-11  13238.78    0
2018-01-12  13740.01    -1
2018-01-13  14210.00    0`

I would like to replace the zeros in the Signal column for either 1 or -1. The final DF should be this:

`Date        Price   Signal
2018-01-01  13380.00    1
2018-01-02  14675.11    1
2018-01-03  14919.51    1
2018-01-04  15059.54    1
2018-01-05  16960.39    1
2018-01-06  17069.79    -1
2018-01-07  16150.03    -1
2018-01-08  14902.54    -1
2018-01-09  14400.00    1
2018-01-10  14907.09    1
2018-01-11  13238.78    1
2018-01-12  13740.01    -1
2018-01-13  14210.00    -1`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace NaNs by preceding values in pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905295/how-to-replace-nans-by-preceding-values-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['Signal'].replace(to_replace=0, method='ffill')
```

(assuming your DataFrame is callled df)

Comment: df['Signal'] = df['Signal'].replace(to_replace=0, method='ffill')

This did the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is propagate previous values to the next rows use the following:

```
df["Signal"] = df["Signal"].ffill()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
```

---

## Prepare a dataframe

If you have a [dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,0,1,0,1], columns=['col1'])
```

[image]

---

## Use pure apply()

You can do:

```
def replace(num):
    if num==1: return 1
    if num==0: return -1
```

Then [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) it to the column holding the values you want to replace:

```
df['new']=df['col1'].apply(replace)
```

---

## apply() lambda functions

You can achieve the same with a [lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890128/why-are-python-lambdas-useful):

```
df['col1'].apply(lambda row: 1 if row == 1 else -1)
```

---

## Use Built-in methods

Using the dataframe we prepared, can do:

```
df['new'] = df['col1'].replace(to_replace=0, value=-1)
```

If you don't want to create a new column, just straight replace the the values in the existing one, can do it [inplace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43893457/understanding-inplace-true):

```
df['col1'].replace(to_replace=0, value=-1,inplace=True)
```

---

## Clean up

If created a *new* column & *don't* want to keep the *old* column, can [drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) it:

```
df.drop('col1',axis=1)
```