# Acces each row and check each column value in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

[image: I have dataset that looks like this]

I want to iterate over each row and and want to check in each column if value is NaN if it is then i want to replace it with the previous value of the same row which is not null.

I believe the prefer way would be using lamba function. But still not figure out to code it
Note: I have thousands of rows and 200 columns in each row

Comment: what do you mean by "previous value"? 
in row (on the left) or in column (above)?

An what if previous value is Nan?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace NaNs by preceding values in pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905295/how-to-replace-nans-by-preceding-values-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: @archer with the previous value of the same row

Comment: @StasBuzuluk i want to go row by row and want to replace it with the previous value of the same row not by column.

Comment: @ArslanAliAwan yes, I see, retracted my flag - sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the work:

```
df.fillna(method='ffill', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Can you please clarify what you want to be done with NaNs in first column(s)?

Comment: your code line basically replaces the NaN values with its previous value whichis not null. ANd it seems exaclty what i want

Answer (score 1):

i think you can use this -

```
your_df.apply(lambda x : x.fillna(method='ffill'), axis=1)
```