# How to populate NaN by 0, starting after first non-nan value

Tags: python, pandas, fillna

I need to populate `NaN` values of my `df` by a static `0`, starting from the first non-nan value.

In a way, combining `method="ffill"` (identify the first value per column, and only act on following `NaN` values) with `value=0` (populating by 0, not the variable quantity in df).

How can I do that? This post is close, but not it: [How to replace NaNs by preceding or next values in pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905295/how-to-replace-nans-by-preceding-or-next-values-in-pandas-dataframe)

Example df

```
     0    1    2
0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  6.0  NaN  1.0
2  NaN  3.0  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  4.0
```

Desired output:

```
     0    1    2
0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  6.0  NaN  1.0
2  0.0  3.0  0.0
3  0.0  0.0  4.0
```

If possible, `df.fillna(value=0, method='ffill')` would be great. But that returns `ValueError: Cannot specify both 'value' and 'method'.`

Edit: Oh, and time matters. We are talking ~60M rows and 4k columns - so looping is out of the question, and masking only if really, really fast

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `mask()`, `ffill()` and `fillna()`:

```
df=df.fillna(df.mask(df.ffill().notna(),0))
#OR via where
df=df.fillna(df.where(df.ffill().isna(),0))
```

output:

```
    0       1       2
0   NaN     NaN     NaN
1   6.0     NaN     1.0
2   0.0     3.0     4.0
3   0.0     0.0     0.0
```

Comment: Amazing - and very strong combination of the existing tools, thanks. Would be terriffic to have this built-in into fill, no? Allowing both value and method, with `value` taking precedence over default, if specified, and `method` indicating direction

Comment: @KingOtto sorry sir didn't understand that what you are trying to say!!!